# How to read excel using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, script, shell-script, .bash-profile

How to extract data from excel such that in first column having the details of machine and in second column having multiple user name and it read excel like it will delete all users from column 2 through machine name which is written in column 1.
Script which I tried-

clear all

sheetname = @()

```
$excel=new-object -com excel.application
$wb=$excel.workbooks.open("c:\users\administrator\my_test.xls")
for ($i=1; $i -le $wb.sheets.count; $i++)
{
  $sheetname+=$wb.Sheets.Item($i).Name;
}
```

But unable to read in the format which I want to run.

Comment: It’s difficult to manipulate an Excel document in C# or C++ it’s more involved than just opening the file.

Comment: You should resort to .csv (comma separated values) files. You can save an excelsheet as .csv and powershell can read and write to them as objects, so it is very easy to work with that. That said, as your current question is formulated, it is very hard to read what the real problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Lots of examples of how to use PowerShell to control/manipulate any MS Office file type and more, as well as on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+ms+excel).

Answer (score 7):

In Powershell, you can use the great `ImportExcel` module to handle all sorts of excel data:

```
# First-time setup, install the module:
Install-Module ImportExcel

# Import the module:
Import-Module ImportExcel

# Now, import the data from your existing excel document:
$Sheet = Import-Excel -Path 'c:\folder\file.xlsx' -WorksheetName Sheet1

# Display the data by using the column names:
$Sheet | Select 'Computername','Username'
```

You didn't say what your data looks like, or what you want to do with it, but here's an example:

```
# List the data, except the users for certain computername values
$Filtered = $Sheet | Where Computername -NotLike "*BadComputer*" |
  Select Computername,User

# Export the manipulated data back to a new excel sheet
$Filtered | Export-Excel -Path 'c:\folder\file.xlsx' -WorksheetName FilteredSheet
```